# array.include() in while loop crash

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to use in while loop if array.includes then add value to hash.
Unfortunately when I add .includes function in to if statement JavaScript crashes.

```
const test = {
  start: 16,
  end: 22,
};

const x = {
  time: [17, 19],
};

export const TimeTable = () => {
  const map = new Map();

  let i = test.start;
  while (i < test.end) {
    console.log(x.time.some((t) => t == i));

    if (x.time.include(i) {
      map.set(i, new Array(i, ++i));
    }
  }
  return;
};
```

Comment: You only conditionally increment `i`, so when the condition is not met, the loop repeats infinitely without any state change.

Comment: There's no `.includes()`, you have `.some()`. But `x.time.some((t) => t == i)` is equivalent to `x.time.includes(i)` when the values are all the same type.

Comment: Instead of a `while` loop use a `for` loop. `for (let i = test.start; i < test.end; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

I have added else as @jsejcksn mentioned where is also incremented `i`.

```
 for (let i = test.start; i < test.end; ) {
if (x.time.includes(i)) {
  i++;
} else {
  map.set(i, new Array(i, i++));
}
```

}